# application cannot be downloaded on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iOS app which i have sent to my client

1.Through test flight, when he is trying to install the app, there is an alert displaying that "app cannot be installed".

1. When the same app is synced with iTunes, the message i am getting is "app failed to install"

Comment: Are you sure that your client's device is in your provisioning profile ?

Comment: Yes its under provisioning profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be due to several reasons.  Most commonly, you need to be sure that the client's device is included in the adhoc distribution profile.  In addition, you need to be sure that the device has no current restrictions enabled (in System Preferences).